# InvalidArgumentException when calling IBAction iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is kind of weird. I created a button programatically, but when i press it, it gives me an InvalidArgumentException with an unrecognized selector sent to instance... Here's how i create the buton:

```
[placeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectPlace)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And here's the IBAction:

```
-(IBAction)selectPlace:(id)sender
{
        NSLog(@"didn't work");
}
```

Now, if i remove the `(id)sender` parameter from the method, it works without problems. Is there a special property i have t set up for have the `(id)sender` as a parameter in the IBAction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a colon after the method name in the selector, but only when your selector is specifying a method which receives a parameter.  In your instance, a colon is required because the method takes the parameter (id)sender.

If your method didn't have any parameters, you'd be right on the money with no colon.

Comment: Right, how could i've missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
[placeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectPlace:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Notice the `:` after `selectPlace`.